# custom input type in sap.m.Input sap ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a input field (sap.m.Input) for which I need the type as Float.
I tried using the sap.ui.model.type.Float() but it did not work.

How can I use a custom type for my input field. I don't have any binding, just need to set the type of the input field as float.
An example would be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance,
Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, usage of new `sap.ui.model.type.Float` seems to convert the string from OData service (Edm.Decimal) into a real float number. This will work for showing the number correct, but not if you try to write a changed value back (OData two-way-binding).

Therefore I implemented an own type like this:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.package.MyFloat");
sap.ui.model.SimpleType.extend("my.package.MyFloat", {
    formatValue : function(oValue) {
        return oValue;
    },

    parseValue : function(oValue) {
        return oValue;
    },

    validateValue : function(oValue) {
        if (oValue != null && oValue != "" && oValue != undefined) {
            if (isNaN(Number(oValue))) {
                var messageString = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("KEY_TO_ERROR_MESSAGE");
                throw new sap.ui.model.ValidateException(messageString);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I detected one SAP example here:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/de/91/f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm
search for PLZ in the file.

Currently I am searching for a way to add some parameters during the construction of `MyFloat`.

You can use such a type this way:

```
new sap.m.Input({
     value: {
         path : "BindingPathToAttribute",
         type : new my.package.MyFloat({})
     }
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom type like this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        "use strict";
        jQuery.sap.declare('Float');
        jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.base.DataType');
        Float = sap.ui.base.DataType.createType( "Float", 
            { isValid : 
                function(sValue) {
                    return ((sValue % 1) != 0);
                }
            }, sap.ui.base.DataType.getType('number') 
        );
    })();
</script>
```

Now you can use type as Float

Comment: Hi Krishna, 

thanks for the snippet. Does this also ensure that the keyboard displays numbers and "."/"," only? 

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
        var oInp = new sap.m.Input({
            liveChange : function(oEvent){
                debugger;
                var value = parseFloat(oEvent.getSource().getProperty('value'));
                if(value % 1 === 0 || isNaN(value))             
                    valueState = "Error";               
                else
                    valueState = "Success";
                oEvent.getSource().setValueState(valueState);               
              }
        });
        oInp.setType(sap.m.InputType.Number);
```