# How to correct bind a float property against odata service in SAPUI5?

Tags: binding, odata, sapui5

With neary each version of SAPUI5 I have strange problems with the `sap.ui.model.type.Float` data type in combination with an ODataModel.

See my old post: [How to handle number format of OData Edm.Decimal in sapui5 correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547654/how-to-handle-number-format-of-odata-edm-decimal-in-sapui5-correct)

Later I build a hack to solve the problem (SAPUI5 1.26.x) that worked and looked like mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27147305/3783327

This was well working. Now I try to upgrade to 1.28.12 and to the `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` model.

I have the following situation:

- Edm.Decimal on server sending decimals in English locale (seperator is a .)
- Frontend should handle user language but at least German

I bind the control with the usage of the following type:

```
return new sap.ui.model.type.Float({
    maxFractionDigits : 2,
    minFractionDigits: 2,
    source : {
        maxFractionDigits : 2,
        minFractionDigits: 2                        
    }
});
```

According to the documentation the `source` is used to define the model format.

If I use it as posted the post will have a comma as seperator instead of a dot.

If I don't use it, the model will receive a float instead of a string (same problem as with 1.26.x).

What is the correct solution to bind a `Edm.Decimal` with the `Float` datatype so that I can enter the number in the user locale of the browser and it will always be send correct to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I detected following documentation:
https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f30dbf6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

If link does not work search for `sap.ui.model.type.Float` in `https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com`

I use now the following code:

```
            return new sap.ui.model.type.Float({
                maxFractionDigits : 2,
                minFractionDigits: 2,
                source : {
                    groupingSeparator: ",",
                    decimalSeparator: ".",
                    groupingEnabled: false,
                    maxFractionDigits : 2,
                    minFractionDigits: 2                        
                }
            });
```

Looks very complex to just show the Edm.Decimal, not sure if there is a easier solution? I would expect that the client `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` is smarter, but maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same problem you did and can't find a proper solution by researching. By now, i am using the following method to parse the needed string out of the inputfield, which has a value of type sap.ui.model.type.Float:

```
new sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal().parseValue(input.value, "float");
```

After that, you can assign this string to the OData Entry you want to create/update.

Not sure if this is a good solution as i am very new to sapui5... Just wanted to share my thoughts on this topic.